# AWS Questions surrounding instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, javabeans

Good Morning i have questions surrounding AWS

Question One

1. Can i create a single instance that is used specifically for DEV that can be used by multiple developers EG one instance but can cater for multiple projects baseline for ENV should be PHP for example
2. how do i then specify an instance for a client to be able to test based on question one
3. how do i then provision a instance for a clients live environment

I want to create template that i can use for this or do i need to create a instance every time to complete the above tasks

Question Two
Can i achieve the above using Elastic beanstalk is it cheaper and more practical

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would think you just simply launch one instance for each of your use cases, set the necessary security group and public ips(elastic IP) to allow for those users. And then production environment in its on VPC or at least subnet and with a back up in a second availability zone?

Hard to give any specific advise without more details on the respective requirements.